# divide a row to separate columns based on content and without two *ngFor iterations

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dynamic-forms

I would like to put a text-box in col-6 and other types in other col-6 so they can be next to each other.

I have tried using 2 *ngFor iterations and it is displaying which I want but can we do with only one iteration?

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hunqiq

Answer (score 1):

I guess the ngfor is overriding row and column.

Comment: true but do you got any solution to handle this?

Comment: Most prob by separating two loops. Not sure though

Comment: I have resolved this issue by doing 2 iterations separately